# How do I cancel a file upload started by ajaxSubmit() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have code similar to the following:

```
UploadWidget.prototype.setup_form_handling = function() {
    var _upload_widget = this;
    $('form#uploader')
    .unbind('trigger-submit-form')  // This might be our company's own method
    .bind('trigger-submit-form', function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        $form.ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, status, xhr, form) {
                // ...
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                // ...
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
};
```

Is there a way to use, say, the reset button of the form to cancel the upload process? Or would I have to navigate to the current page (refresh) in order to stop everything?

I tried making a variable stored by the UploadWidget object that stores the jqXHR value (and calling `var _upload_widget.jqXHR = $form.ajaxSubmit({ ... });`), but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: I've discovered that this widget creates an iFrame upon initializing the upload and uses that for the upload process. I can remove the iFrame, but the file is still uploaded in full, in the background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unlike `jQuery.ajax()`, `ajaxForm()` and `ajaxSubmit()` of the jQuery form plugin do not return the jqXHR object.  There are other ways to get the jqXHR object, though:

### `data()` method on the form object (easiest way)

`ajaxSubmit()` returns the form object. You can call the `data()` method on this form object to get the XHR object:

```
var form = $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({ ... });
var xhr = form.data('jqxhr');
```

Then call `xhr.abort()` when you want to abort the upload.

This functionality was added in December 2012; see [issue 221](https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/221). (shukshin.ivan's answer was the first to point this out.)

### `beforeSend` callback (for jQuery Form versions before December 2012)

In addition to the [options listed in the jQuery form plugin site](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object), `ajaxForm()` and `ajaxSubmit()` will also take any of the [jQuery.ajax() options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  One of the options is a `beforeSend` callback, and the callback signature is `beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)`.

So, specify a `beforeSend` callback function, and the jqXHR object will be passed in as the first parameter of that callback.  Save that jqXHR object, and then you can call `abort()` on that jqXHR object when you want to abort the upload.

Answer (score 2):

Since Dec 2012 it is possible to access xhr directly:

```
var form = $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({ ... });
var xhr = form.data('jqxhr');
....
$('#cancel').on('click', function(){
    xhr.abort();
});
```

src - https://github.com/malsup/form/issues/221

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way:

```
var myForm  = null; 
myForm = $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
               url: ajaxUrl,
               beforeSubmit : function() {
                   if(myForm != null)
                      myForm.data('jqxhr').abort();
                   },
               ...
          });
```

This will stop your previous ajaxSubmit requests.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
window.stop();
```

which mimics the stop button being pressed. Not entirely sure that IE likes it though. For IE, you could try:

```
document.execCommand('Stop');
```