# Abort file upload with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How is it possible to cancel a pending post request using JavaScript/JQuery?

I have an upload form for large files and want to offer the possibility to abort the upload after the submit button is triggered without reloading the whole page.

Comment: I think pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> works just fine on many browsers.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601841/how-do-i-cancel-a-file-upload-started-by-ajaxsubmit-in-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ //stuff}); 
//To canel call abort(). 
xhr.abort();
```

However, I do think this requires further investigation. I just looked up if jquery calls onaboort which is the dom's event for "stop waiting"/abort for the response.